# cite not working with 2 arguments

Tags: citing, arguments

I want to include a reference with text before the citation in parentheses, like so: "(e.g., Brautigam & Bell, 1995)". I have to use the \cite command, because it's a journal template with strict rules, but it doesn't render correctly when using two arguments. I am using bibtex and it seems to be linked correctly.

In my latex file:

```
\cite [one][two]{brautigam1995crresele}
```

In the pdf:

[image]

In the Texshop console:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `[' undefined on input line 228.
```

---

With just one argument it seems to be fine:

```
\cite [one]{brautigam1995crresele}
```

In the pdf:

[image]

But of course I need the second argument to make 'e.g.' appear before the reference. Adding { and } around the command does not help. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you remove the space between `cite` and `[`?

Comment: Not all implementation of `\cite` support two optional arguments. The standard implementation from the LaTeX kernel only has one optional argument for the page number/postnote, but no argument for the prenote. `natbib` and `biblatex` support two optional arguments, some other citation *packages* (real packages loaded with `\usepackage`, not bibliography styles called with `\bibliographstyle`) may or may not define a prenote argument or a equivalent replacement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**

As mentionned in a comment by [moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe), the `natbib` package provides the command `\citep` which accepts two optional arguments such that `\citep[one]{brautigam1995crresele}` will give the "normal" behavior of `\cite`, `\citep[one][]{brautigam1995crresele}` will use `one` as a prenote and nothing as a postnote and `\citep[one][two]{brautigam1995crresele}` will use `one` as a prenote and `two` as a postnote.

This implementation is cleaner that the one proposed in the original answer below.

**Original answer**

The problem here is that we don't know what class file your editor is using and if it redefines the `\cite` command, allowing for the use of two optional arguments.
Indeed, as far as I know, the `\cite` command only takes one optional argument and the label of the bibliographical entry as a mandatory argument.

Without this information, a solution (a bit overkill, I admit), would be to declare a new command having two optional arguments (requiring the use of `xargs`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xargs}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\newcommandx{\mycite}[3][1 =, 2 =]{%
    \ifthenelse{
        \isempty{#1}{}
    }{
        \ifthenelse{
            \isempty{#2}{}
        }{
            \cite{#3}
        }{
            \cite[#2]{#3}
        }
    }{
        \ifthenelse{
            \isempty{#2}{}
        }{
            #1,\xspace\cite{#3}
        }{
            #1,\xspace\cite[#2]{#3}
        }
    }
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@article{olfati2004consensus,
  title={Consensus problems in networks of agents with switching topology and time-delays},
  author={Olfati-Saber, Reza and Murray, Richard M},
  journal={IEEE Transactions on automatic control},
  volume={49},
  number={9},
  pages={1520--1533},
  year={2004}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\mycite[one][two]{olfati2004consensus}

\mycite[][two]{olfati2004consensus}

\mycite[one]{olfati2004consensus}

\mycite[one][]{olfati2004consensus}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

The above codes yields:

[image: Result of <code>\mycite</code> command]

However, if your editor is really strict about defining new commands, you might have no other option than to write "e.g.," by hand before your `\cite` command.

Comment: I switched to the journal's template in Overleaf which (for some reason) uses citep instead, and your first suggestion worked. Thanks for your insight!